# Making objects shared across DLL's

Tags: c++, dll, plugins

I wrote a modular system with DLL's (or .so's, it's cross-platform). These separate plugins have to hook into the main system's objects.

E.G.
You have a vector of strings in one object, the owner is the main application. Now several (explicit loaded) plugins must access that vector.

These plugins need also a baseclass, a sort of API to hook into the main system.

I tried including all the header files into the DLL, but there are two problems with that: the I include the API each time I build an plugin. 
The second is: for static methods, I need a cpp file, but then he doesn't use the cpp file from the main application, but his own. This causes problem with that shared vector... (since there are now multiple vectors, one main, and one per plugin)

Any ideas?

Comment: `You have a vector of strings in one object, the owner is the main application. Now several (explicit loaded) plugins must access that vector.`  If I build my plugin with a different compiler or different compiler options than your main DLL, the program may crash when accessing this vector.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit problematic as Paul mentioned. When accessing a vector (probably you're talking about std::vector) which was instantiated in another module (exe/dll), you have to be careful. If both modules are compiled with the same compiler, same compiler settings, same STL implementation and you're only reading from it (especially not pushing additional values, as that may reallocate the internal buffer and cause problems when accessing the memory), you should be fine.

However if you cannot guarantee such setup, it would be better to provide access to raw data array together with its size, not via std::vector directly, but rather via the [std::vector::data()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/). If the stored data type (template type T of std::vector) is binary compatible between the two communicating modules, such interface should be safe.

There is a C++ standard proposal to fix such issues: [Defining a Portable C++ ABI](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/05/n4028). Hopefully it will prevent such problems in the future.

Comment: That's a problem that adds the list, but better prevent than cure... But My problem stays: how do I access that vector trough a dll?

Comment: My recommendation is not to access the vector, but its internal data array instead (for reading). If you need to change the vector contents, then it should probably be done via an external method, which accesses the vector inside.